# how to delegate multiprocessing to a websocket's (on_message) inner functions?

Tags: python, function, websocket, multiprocessing

I am trying to find a way to delegate my computers processing power between two inner functions of my websocket `def on_message()` function. Also, my code seems to skip `def on_message()`, im not too sure if I need to declare these inner functions in the args or not?

Thank you in advance.

```
import websocket
import concurrent.futures as mp

Stock_stream = 'wss://data.alpaca.markets/stream'


def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")


def on_message(ws, message):
    def job():

        print("do job")
        with mp.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
            results = pool.map(job)
            return results

    def trade():

        print("trade")
        with mp.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
            results = pool.map(trade)
            return results


def on_close(ws):
    print("bye")


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(Stock_stream, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I know, *websocket-client* is a synchronous lib. Therefore, when you need to do a long processing before a response, use multithreading. In your case run in thread `job()` or `trade()` and pass `ws` to them.

```
...
def on_message(ws, message):

    def job(ws):
        print("do job")
        with mp.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
            results = pool.map(job)
            # send result to ws

    threading.Thread(target=job, args=(ws,), daemon=True).start()
...
```